# Font color of list item doesn't inherit correctly from CSS

Tags: html, css, haml

I have the following headermenu:

```
%div.header
  %div.span-25
    = link_to logo, root_path
  %div.span-25
    %div.headermenu
      %ul
        - if current_page?(root_path)
          %li.currentmenu
            = link_to "Home", root_path
        - else
          %li
            = link_to "Home", root_path
        - if current_page?(user_path)
          %li.currentmenu
            = link_to "User", user_path
        - else
          %li
            = link_to "User", user_path
```

In the styleshhet I have:

```
.headermenu {
  border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
  margin-top:-5px;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  height:42px;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:transparent url('darkgray_background.gif') repeat-x top;
  font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvitica,sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.headermenu ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  width:auto;
}

.headermenu ul li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0 1px 0 0;
}

.headermenu ul li a {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:13px 12px 0 12px;
  height:28px;
}

.currentmenu {
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  background:transparent url('darkgray_backgroundOVER.gif') no-repeat top center;
}
```

So, the current header menu will be highlighted. The background image of the highlighted menu is correct ('darkgray_backgroundOVER.gif'), but the font is black (#000), and not #fff as it supposed to be. Firebug shows a cancelled out font from currentmenu:

Inherited from li.currentmenu
element.style { <s>color: #FFFFFF;</s>}

Instead above this is shows:

.headermenu ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    etc....
}

Why doesn't it display the font in white? In black it's almost not legible. What can I do to have the font of the current menu in white and keep the font of the other (not current menus) in black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the color on the anchor tag itself, not just the menu class. Your CSS isn't specific enough, and so the #000 over-rides.

```
li.currentmenu a{ 
color:#fff;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:transparent url('darkgray_backgroundOVER.gif') no-repeat top center;
}
```

will be more specific and should target the anchor tag correctly.

Comment: .headermenu ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 13px 12px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
custom.css?body=1 (line 268)
li.currentmenu a {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: url("darkgray_backgroundOVER.gif") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    <s>color: #FFFFFF;</s>
}

Comment: the last line (color: #FFFFFF) is cancelled out

Comment: Add the !important to his code and it should work, I should have had the specific selector in mine to begin with. I'll edit it now. Between the two answers it should work.

Comment: We answered at exactly the same time Rick.

Comment: Also, adding !important is bad practice and isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a specificity issue, just do this:

```
li.currentmenu a{
color:#fff !important;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
background:transparent url('darkgray_backgroundOVER.gif') no-repeat top center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `.currentmenu` selector isn't as specific as `.headermenu ul li a`.

Just change `.currentmenu` selector to `.headermenu .currentmenu a`

```
.headermenu .currentmenu a {
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:5px;
  -moz-border-radius:5px;
  background:transparent url('darkgray_backgroundOVER.gif') no-repeat top center;
}
```